# Selenium Webdriver .get() not opening window - no errors

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to open google using selenium. When I run this, no error appears in the console however a chrome window does not open. The program simply terminates.   I used nearly the same code (and it worked) on my last project when I was on Chrome 78. This uses version 80.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count, freeze_support
import os
import time


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_BIN = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "chromedriver-80-mac")

def get_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_BIN, options=options)
    return driver

def test():
    driver = get_driver()
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.quit()

test()
```

Comment: you are using  this `options.add_argument('--headless')` .Means chrome will run in background.To see window open you need to comment that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a headless environment, which means you won't see a window. If you want to see a window, remove this line of code:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Comment: Brb, need to drink some coffee.